# Should functions that call a callback function be bound?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If I pass a callback function from `Parent` to `GrandChild`, should `handleClick` be bound in `Child` and `GrandChild`?

**Parent.js**

```
class Parent extends React {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Clicked!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

**Child.js**

```
class Child extends React {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { onClick: callback } = this.props;

    callback();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GrandChild onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

**GrandChild.js**

```
class GrandChild extends React {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { onClick: callback } = this.props;

    callback();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If the callback from the parent referenced `this`, would you want it to point to the parent or the child? Probably the parent, so it can access the parent's properties. If the child needs to intercept the call, it can create a new callback, bind itself to that, and then call the original callback (that came from the parent) from inside the new callback.

Comment: There is no need to have `handleClick` methods in `Child` and `GrandChild` if all they are doing is pass the click handler along. You can just directly write `<GrandChild onClick={this.props.onClick} />` and `<div onClick={this.prop.onClick} />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions can be accessed via props without being bound when passed down to children. It's only necessary to bind to `this` inside the component where the function is originally defined.

You only need to do `onClick={this.props.handeClick}`

or if you want to pass some data, you can do it like this:

```
onClick={(someData) => this.props.handeClick(someData)}
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, you only need to bind handleClick in Parent.js. You can then just pass this function down via props and access it in the child components using `this.props`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function is better. And context `this` will be automatically bind.

```
handleClick = () => {}
```

Inline function is bad (unnecessary render possible). It is better like this:

```
handleClick = (someData) => this.props.handeClick(someData)
```

And

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

Comment: `handleClick = () => {}` inside a class body is not valid JavaScript yet. It's a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the context `this` should always be the one where the logic is, so if the logic that handles the `handleClick` is in the class `Parent` so, the context is.

Other than that there are some problems in your code.

1.Your component classes must extend `React.Component` or `React.PureComponent` and not `React` itself (maybe it's a copy-paste error, but if not fix it).

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

2.You don't have to name every single props that should be passed through all child components, you can use the spread syntax if you code using ES6.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // this is passing all props of Child to GrandChild
      <GrandChild {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}
```

3.For components that don't have state, use `function` instead of `class`, it's more performant and also the code is smaller.

```
function Child(props) {
  return (
    <GrandChild {...props} />
  );
}
```

Finally your code could look like this:

```
function Parent(props) {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
  return <Child onClick={handleClick} />;
}

function Child(props) {
  return <GrandChild {...props} />;
}

function GrandChild(props) {
  return <div onClick={props.onClick} />;
}
```